# Show that a function is complex analytic in the unit disk by finding the power series representation

Tags: complex-analysis

Show the function $f(z)= \frac{1}{(1-z^6)^3}$ is complex analytic on the unit disk by finding the power series representation of $f$ at 0 explicitly. And using the coefficients of this series, verify that the radius of convergence is 1.

In my mind, if I use cauchy's integral formula for find $a_n$ and then plug that into $\sum^\infty_0 a_nz^n$ and I should be done.

So
\begin{align*}
a_n&= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D_1(0)} \frac{1}{(1-\zeta^6)^3\zeta^{n+1}}d\zeta
\\&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{1}{(1-e^{i6t})^3e^{int}}dt
\end{align*}
But I am having a hard time integrating this expression. Can anyone give me some hints?
or am I going into the right direction?

Comment: Do you know the series  expansion of $(1+c)^{-3}$  for $|c|<1$?

Comment: Look up the generalised binomial theorem.

Comment: Thanks! I looked up the generalized binomial theorem and I think using that I can conclude $$f(z)= \sum^\infty_{r=0} {n \choose r} z^{6r}= \sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n(n+1)(n+2)z^{6n}$$ I think I can use this to argue that $f$ is complex analytic since its already in a power series form. And then for the converge I should be able to use one of the series convergence test to do it. Then this really do not feel like a complex problem.